# Windex in a keyboard

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure

After noticing that the screen and keyboard on his laptop were dirty were dirty, my friend used a [Windex](https://www.windex.com/en-US/Pages/default.aspx) spray to clean them. (not on my advice.... ;)

Now most of the keys on his keyboard, when pushed, will register 4-5 keys on the computer. (Thankfully the screen still appears to be fine :)

Any fixes? Should I tell him to consult a professional?

---

*Asus [X200](http://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X200CA/) laptop, touch screen, Windows 8.1 (but probably equally applicable to all laptops).*

Comment: I don't understand. You're framing this like Windex broke his keyboard, yet you describe an improvement. I suggest spray more Windex in it.

Comment: If none of the keyboards worked, and now some of them work, it was always a hardware problem.  If its under warranty send it in.  He shouldn't use Windex on his screen in the future.  There normally sin't a solution for a broken laptop keyboard.

Comment: @JasonC Huh????

Comment: @AnotherUser You said none of his keys worked. Then he sprayed Windex in it. And now some do. :P

Comment: I already did. I guarantee you the problems with the keyboard are because of the habit of using window cleaner on a laptop. Send the laptop in to be fixed under warranty.

Comment: @Ramhound Agreed....so remove hardware-failure tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that [Windex and other products with ammonia shouldn't be used on LCD panels](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/maintenance/ht/cleanflatscreen.htm) ("These chemicals can ... permanently discolor the screen or cause other kinds of damage"), it smells of a hardware problem.

If the Windex caused the problem, I suppose you could try removing the battery and spraying out the keyboard with [electrical contact cleaner](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2102649), although it might be a long shot if permanent damage was done.

Many laptops have replaceable keyboards, and you can usually search the manufacturers page, Amazon, newegg, or e.g. [various parts sites](http://www.laptoppartsexpert.com/) for replacements. Be sure you get the correct parts. The X200's keyboard may not be replaceable, in which case, you may be out of luck, but do some research first.

If the machine is still under warranty and your warranty covers damage like this you could contact ASUS or the vendor for a service request.

If the machine is not under warranty and you cannot find the replacement parts (and/or do not feel comfortable replacing them) then you could try and find an experienced repair center, they may have some advice.

Comment: My plan was to use a slighty damp towel to wipe down the inside, and then let dry....do I need to use 'electrical contact cleaner' if I want this to work?

Comment: Also "_Ignoring the fact that Windex and other products with ammonia shouldn't be used on LCD panels_" -- I certainly didn't tell him to do it :P

Comment: @AnotherUser You could wipe it down with a damp towel but you'll need to give it plenty of time to dry, which may be longer than you think if water gets trapped in odd places. The thing with the contact cleaner is 1) it sprays with some force, allowing you to get into tight places and also blow off any residue, 2) it's a solvent that can take care of more things than water, 3) it dries very quickly, 4) it's nonconductive. It's definitely the best tool for the job. So you could certainly try water first; but if the contact cleaner doesn't do the trick then most likely nothing will.

Comment: If you have a Radio Shack or electronic-y store (an electronic music store might have it too) nearby it should be easy to find.

Comment: My friend went out and got some; opened computer and sprayed keyboard top and bottom.....now drying....hopefully it will work!

Comment: Didn't work :( ....I think we'll just have to buy a replacement keyboard from ASUS

Comment: I'm new to this site....why do you think someone downvoted the question?

Comment: @AnotherUser They expect that the question have very clear information, that does not confuse the reader.   Without bugging you you only gave it 5 hours to dry out. If water (windex is 98%) gets under the membranes of a membrane keyboard it could take 2 weeks to dry. it capilaries in, but there is no air movement under there, so it takes forever to dry out.  It is possible given way more time it could dry out. It is unlikely to be actually damaged, likely to still be wet in places.

Comment: @Psycogeek I didn't realize it could take that long to dry.....

Comment: @Psycogeek What "very clear information" is the question missing?

Answer (score 1):

Just to have other methods on record, I asked a (different) friend, who suggested two other possible solutions (yet to be tried!) for this problem:

- Soak in 99% isopropyl alcohol followed by rice, to clean out and dry out the keyboard.
- Buy a cheap, used computer of the same model, and take the keyboard from it.